# Passing data to a maps class in android

Tags: java, android, maps

So I'm working on a project for my School with a group and we're thinking about implementing a way to have a list of faculty and staff and have an option to "map them" or their office on a campus map on android. We have the map working currently with itemizedOverlays and zoom in and out features.

My question is when someone who uses this android app selects a faculty and staff member, how can I pass their information ( Which will just be their name ) to our maps class and use it with itemizedOverlays?

code is here:
 http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mtsu-andriod/source/browse/trunk/%20mtsu-andriod%20--username%20craigmurphy88%40gmail.com/MTSU%20Android/src/com/MTSUAndroid/CampusMap.java

we will be passing the teacher's name FROM the person class, TO the maps class.

Comment: You should accept an answer to increase your reputation or at least to appreciate the efforts of the person who answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the Intent Extra parameters as described here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

```
private long lat, lng;
//.. onCreate
   lat = getIntent().getLongExtra("lat");
   lng = getIntent().getLongExtra("lon");

//...
GeoPoint office = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(office, "", "");
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(oi);
//.. and so on.
```

On the Tap, you can launch your map intent like this ('i' is your map intent and 't' your Teacher Object):

```
i.putExtra("lat", t.getPos().getLat());
i.putExtra("lng", t.getPos().getLng());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Im Goona try it and mention it to our group! I love stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't understand your point. If you want a particular alert to display on the tap event, you could extend OverlayItem in order for it to have an extra param with your "Person ID" or something. Then on the onTap method in the overlay, get the Person that corresponds to that ID (after casting your object, of course). And display the alert accordingly.

The same goes if you want to display an overlay (or a set of overlay items) according to the previously chosen element. This should be fairly simple by either passing a param to the CampusMap constructor or (an ugly approach but faster one) storing the chosen item in a static class and accessing it from the Map.

Comment: Well we're going to have a list of faculty and staff on campus with their first and last name. You can click on them and then it will display certain information about them. It will also have 4 button options. One of them is called "map it" and it will show where the teacher's office is located on campus. 

My question is how can I pass that teachers information to the OnTap method I suppose. Since the that information is in a different class than the map class.

Comment: I get it. Just pass either the complete class, or the GPS lat long, to the Map. And add an extra Overlay Item for this lat long. You could even create a new Constructor for your MapView class which receives the Teacher class (with his/her office position) and print it accordingly.

Comment: You could also use the Intent Extra parameters as described here:

 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

`
private long lat, lng;
//.. onCreate
   lat = getIntent().getLongExtra("lat");
   lng = getIntent().getLongExtra("lon");

//...
GeoPoint office = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(office, "", "");
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(oi);
//.. and so on.
`

On the Tap, you can launch your map intent like this ('i' is your map intent and 't' your Teacher Object):

`
i.putExtra("lat", t.getPos().getLat());
i.putExtra("lng", t.getPos().getLng());
`